# Design constraint in OOP election system

Tags: oop

I am trying to build an OOP design for an election system.

A citizen can nominate themselves to be a contender. So all contenders are citizens. I was thinking of keeping the relation ship IS-A by having contender extend citizen, but I am not able to understand how i will have a citizen nominate themselves then.

Citizen can become followers of contenders and receive a mail about any idea they post. Further more if they receive a mail and were also a contender they would send mail to their followers.

eg.

```
class Citizen {
   public:
     bool Citizen::nominate(Eboard* b) {
         return b->addContender(Contender(this));
     }
}

class Contender: public Citizen {
      Citizen* c;
    public:
      Contender(Citizen* c);
}
```

(1) I first thought it is fine to not have an ISA relationship. But with the mail constraint, i need to maintain a list of base class objects, as followers can be citizen or contenders.

(2) When system is required to maintain some constraints, take additional actions upon things like candidate giving rating- should the system be passed by reference from the main or should this be directly able to get the system singleton and operate on that.

Can someone please help me with the design choice here?

Comment: This might be a better question for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)